# r plot one histogram above another

Tags: r, histogram

I want to be able to recreate the following diagram using r. The main problem being  the stacking of one plot above the other. I am hoping for something simple without the need to go into the depths of such packages as ggplot since the emphasis is on the result of the digram (central limit theorem) rather than programming.

[image]

```
x1<-rnorm(1000,50,10)
x2<-rnorm(1000,50,20)
x3<-rnorm(1000,50,30)
x4<-rnorm(1000,50,40)

xMin=min(x1,x2,x3,x4)
xMax=max(x1,x2,x3,x4)

hist(x1, xlim = c(xMin,xMax))
hist(x2, xlim = c(xMin,xMax))
hist(x3, xlim = c(xMin,xMax))
hist(x4, xlim = c(xMin,xMax))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `par(mfcol=c(4,1))` to stack the different histograms.

```
x1<-rnorm(1000,50,10)
x2<-rnorm(1000,50,20)
x3<-rnorm(1000,50,30)
x4<-rnorm(1000,50,40)
xMin=min(x1,x2,x3,x4)
xMax=max(x1,x2,x3,x4)
par(mfcol=c(4,1))
hist(x1, xlim = c(xMin,xMax))
hist(x2, xlim = c(xMin,xMax))
hist(x3, xlim = c(xMin,xMax))
hist(x4, xlim = c(xMin,xMax))
dev.off()
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would argue that one of the great things about `ggplot2` is that it's intuitive and users can spend more time making quick and easy visualisations like this and less time worrying about the code.

**Base R solution**

```r
x1<-rnorm(1000,50,10)
x2<-rnorm(1000,50,20)
x3<-rnorm(1000,50,30)
x4<-rnorm(1000,50,40)

xMin=min(x1,x2,x3,x4)
xMax=max(x1,x2,x3,x4)


par(mfrow=c(4,1), oma = c(5,2,2,2), mar = c(3, 1, 1, 1))      
hist(x1, xlim = c(xMin,xMax), col='#4281C3', main = NULL)
hist(x2, xlim = c(xMin,xMax), col = '#008437', main = NULL)
hist(x3, xlim = c(xMin,xMax), col= '#F49824', main = NULL)
hist(x4, xlim = c(xMin,xMax), col = '#E42313', main = NULL)
legend('bottom',legend=c("x1", "x2", "x3", 'x4'),
       fill=c("#4281C3", '#008437', "#F49824", '#E42313'),
       horiz = T, inset=c(0,-1), xpd=NA)
```

[image]

**ggplot2 solution**

```r
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
df1 <- gather(data.frame(x1, x2,x3,x4) , 'variable', 'value') 

ggplot(df1) +
  geom_histogram(aes(x = value, fill = variable), colour = '#000000') +
  facet_wrap(.~ variable, nrow = 4) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("#4281C3", '#008437', "#F49824", '#E42313'))
```

[image]

The key to `ggplot2` is to have one column per variable, hence the use of `tidyr::gather` but we could equally have done:

```r
df1 <- data.frame(value = c(x1,x2,x3,x4),
                  variable = rep(c('x1','x2','x3','x4'), each =1000))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're going for absolute ground level basics then `par()` should help you plot several plots in the same window.

```
par(mfrow = c(4,1)) # breaking your graphic windows into 4 rows, 1 column
hist(x1, xlim = c(xMin,xMax))
hist(x2, xlim = c(xMin,xMax))
hist(x3, xlim = c(xMin,xMax))
hist(x4, xlim = c(xMin,xMax))
```

This will plot every histogram above the next but they will have their own legends etc.
To reset the window parameters use `dev.off()`.
For more complex methods that look much nicer, `ggplot` is definitely the go-to, there are countless simple guides online.